# Is there a way to distribute data according to a logic in Excel vba?

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I have an Excel sheet with the below data.

There are 10,000 Data rows.
9000 are of "USA" & 1000 are of "Other" country.

I want to evenly distribute the data so that when I have 9 "USA" followed by 1 "Other" data distributed throughout.

| Name | Country |
| --- | --- |
| Alice | USA |
| Brook | Other |
| Cathy | USA |
| David | USA |
| Esther | Other |
| Freddy | USA |
| Galin | USA |
| Henry | Other |
| Indigo | USA |
| Jenny | USA |
| Kalin | Other |
| Linda | USA |

How do I accomplish this using manual & excel VBA? Appreciate both solutions. Thanks

Comment: Please visit the help pages for asking, e.g. [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and note that among other things, you should do some research and attempt to solve the problem your self first. Your question needs to include what you have tried and describe how it failed. So, please edit your question to show your own attempt.

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved with a formula if you have the newest version of Excel.

Try something like (adapt ranges and what you are filtering on as necessary):

```
=LET(x, FILTER($B$1:$C$12, $C$1:$C$12="a"),
y, FILTER($B$1:$C$12, $C$1:$C$12="b"),
z, ROW(D1:D12), myrows, MAX(z),
ratio, MAX((COUNTA(x)/2)/(COUNTA(y)/2), (COUNTA(y)/2)/(COUNTA(x)/2))+1,
IF(MOD(z,ratio)<>0,
INDEX(x, IF(MOD(SEQUENCE(myrows),ratio)=0, 0, SEQUENCE(myrows)-CEILING(ROW(G1:G12)/ratio-1,1)), SEQUENCE(1,2)),
INDEX(y, IF(MOD(SEQUENCE(myrows),ratio)<>0,0,SEQUENCE(myrows)/ratio), SEQUENCE(1,2))))
```

For example:
[image]

The trick is to create the "correct" sequence for each result; for the first array you want to skip every nth row (in your case 10), and having the nth+1 row not default to n+1, but n, while in the second array you want to skip every row that isn't a some multiple of n, and have the nth rows count sequentially.

A caveat-- as is, I don't believe the formula will work with repetition other than 1, i.e. if you want to do something like 8 rows followed by 2 rows, this won't work.

Comment: You say: *if you have the newest version of Excel*. Did you see the tags `excel-2010` and `excel-2007`?

Answer (score 0):

This works even with older Excel versions:

If this is your data:

[image]

Add a `Sort` column with the following formula in C2 and pull it down:

```
=IF(B2="USA",COUNTIF($B$2:B2,"USA")+INT((COUNTIF($B$2:B2,"USA")-1)/ROUNDUP(COUNTIF(B:B,"USA")/(COUNTA(B:B)-COUNTIF(B:B,"USA")),0)),COUNTIF($B$2:B2,"Other")*(ROUNDUP(COUNTIF(B:B,"USA")/(COUNTA(B:B)-COUNTIF(B:B,"USA")),0)+1))
```

Then sort by this column C and `USA` and `Other` are evenly spread:

[image]